How to make nested element scrollable without using `flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-hidden` repeatedly?
I am creating a UI using Tailwind CSS. For simplicity, let's say the UI looks like this:
<div class="h-full">
    <div> <p> Some text </p> </div>
    <div> <button> Click me </button> </div>
    <form>
        <input>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>
            <div> more text </div>
            <div> <!-- I want this <div> to scroll through the content -->
                <div class="h-[2000px]"> Alot of content overflowing the screen! </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

All these elements are placed in a vertical flow. The div with h-[2000px] is deeply nested in my UI, and because of its size, I want to make the parent div scroll through the large div. I had a hard time making this work, but finally figured out this solution:
<div class="h-full flex flex-col">
    <div> <p> Some text </p> </div>
    <div> <button> Click me </button> </div>
    <form class="flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-hidden">
        <input>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-hidden">
            <div> more text </div>
            <div class="flex flex-1 overflow-auto">
                <div class="h-[2000px]"> Alot of content overflowing the screen! </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

I have to set the classes flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-hidden on every nested layer of elements, and to make the nested div scrollable, I have to set flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-auto. In this example, the large element is not that deeply nested, but in my real case scenario, I am writing flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-hidden about 5 times. This ends up getting hard to keep track of...
Is there any simpler way of making a large element deeply nested within the DOM scrollable?

I guess, just adding overflow-auto or overflow-y-scroll would do? https://play.tailwindcss.com/Y8VnATXE51

This is my approach:
<body>
  <main class="max-h-screen bg-green-200">
    <div><p>Some text</p></div>
    <div><button>Click me</button></div>
    <form>
      <input />
      <div>text</div>
      <div>text</div>
      <div>
        <div>more text</div>
        <div class="max-h-48 overflow-y-scroll">
          <div class="h-[2000px] bg-red-200">Alot of content overflowing the screen!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="h-[2000px] bg-purple-200">Another content that will overflow main as usual!</div>
  </main>
</body>


But this requires you to set an overflowing height (max-h-48 in my case).
I understand you want the div to overflow to the end of the page. In this case I would do something like this to avoid too many flex components:
<body>
  <main class="h-screen overflow-hidden">
    <div><p>Some text</p></div>
    <div><button>Click me</button></div>
    <form class="h-full">
      <input />
      <div>text</div>
      <div>text</div>
      <div class="h-full">
        <div>more text</div>
        <div class="h-full overflow-y-scroll">
          <div class="h-[2000px] bg-red-200">Alot of content overflowing the screen!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>

